# How to check datareader and compare it with another value?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I want to check my data reader value and compare it with another value I use this peace of code but it does not work.

```
ol_com.CommandText = "select [card_id] from student_info where [card_id] = '" + card_No.Text + "'";
reader = ol_com.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.IsDBNull(0) && reader["card_id"] == "-")
{
   //do my work here
}//end if

else
{
    //give a message
}//end else
```

Comment: Any exception or error message? And use [parameterized sql](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) please. This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: You missed `reader.Read()`

Comment: You haven't called `Read`, so you haven't moved onto the first result. Also, you're using the indexer of the reader which has a declared type of `object`, but you're using `==` to compare it with `string`. That's not going to do what you want.

Comment: it is not problem for me if i use sql parameters or not ... my problem is this code does no what i need it gives me error say no column/row exist

Comment: jon skeet ... can gives me some code ... how i do it?

Comment: @HunarA.Ahmad how do you expect the value to be both DBNull and "-" ?

Comment: @HunarA.Ahmad call the Read() function before if statement "reader.Read();"

Comment: nithin nayagam ... why not my reader can be null or "-" or any other thing?

Comment: @HunarA.Ahmad a value can be `null` or something but not `null` and `-`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel   ... it can be null or "-" or not null i mean if null or "-" do my job and if not null (any other things) give message

Comment: if(reader.Read() && reader[0] as string == "-")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx)

**The default position of the SqlDataReader is before the first record. Therefore, you must call Read to begin accessing any data.**

so you must call the Read() function to get to the 1st record

The Read() method returns a boolean- true if any rows were returned, false if no row was returned

```
ol_com.CommandText = "select [card_id] from student_info where [card_id] = '" + card_No.Text + "'";
reader = ol_com.ExecuteReader();
if(reader.Read())
{
  if (reader.IsDBNull(0) || reader["card_id"].ToString() == "-")
  {
   //do my work here
  }//end if

  else
  {
    //give a message
  }//end else
}

else
{
  //give message that given value does not exist in database
}
```

and you should use || (OR) operator and not && (AND) because a value can NOT be BOTH DBNull **AND** "-". It can only be DBNull **OR** "-"

Comment: if i enter "-" it gives me a message and if i enter another value that is not in card_id column it gives error say no data exist for row/column?

Comment: check the return value of reader.Read() to check if there is a record see my comment on your opening post